# List of indoor exercises, which doesn't require any tools, and affects the whole body

Tags: exercise, home-exercise, routine

I have a simple request, I want a list of exercises which I can do in my room, and doesn't require any tools, and will affect the whole body.

I only want to be physically stronger to a point where I can defend my self and do work which requires above average physical strength.

I don't aim for bigger muscles or better appearance, I don't care about that, rather I don't want to have that full-muscles look (I don't know how to explain it).

I don't aim for weight lose, rather the opposite, currently my weight is 50Kg, and I'm 167 cm tall.

As I said earlier, I just want like above average physical strength for the whole body.

I don't have any experience in exercising and training, I'm not athletic at all, and  currently I'm physically weak *(not because of a disease or something, just lake of exercise, because I'm very lazy, but trying to improve)*, and I want to change that.

EDIT: I'm a guy, I don't know if this information will help, but just to make sure.

Also when I said I don't aim for bigger muscles, I don't mean that I don't want muscles look at all, I would like to have somewhat 6 packs or something, I meant that I don't want the jacked look, where the muscles shape is very outstanding, and the veins are clear *(is it even good for veins to be this clear?)*.

Answer (score 2):

This has some really good examples with short GIFS showing how to perform the exercise.

https://www.menshealth.com/uk/building-muscle/a756325/10-best-bodyweight-exercises-for-men/

**1. Press-ups**

*How to do the exercise*

Set up with your weight supported on your toes and hands beneath your shoulders, body straight.
Take care to keep your core locked so a straight line forms between your head, glutes and heels.
Lower your body until your chest is an inch from the ground then explosively drive up by fully extending your arms.

**2. Step-up with Knee Raises**

*How to do the exercise*

Place a bench or a box in front of you and step onto it with one foot.
As you plant your foot, drive with your other foot bringing your knee up as high as you can. Lower it back down and step back onto the floor.
Repeat on the other side.

**3. Groiners**

*How to do the exercise*

Start the exercise in a press-up position.
Jump forward so both legs land next to your hands.
Return to starting position.

**4. Spider Crawl**

*How to do the exercise*

From a press-up position, raise one foot off the floor and bring your knee up towards your elbow.
Pause then return to the starting position and repeat on the other side.
Make sure to crunch your core at the top of the rep to bring your knee even closer to your elbow and get more out of your abs.

**5. Standing Long Jump**

*How to do the exercise*

Lower yourself into a squat position with your feet shoulder-width apart.
Swing your arms back and use them to propel yourself forward.
Bring your legs forward for additional momentum.
Jump as far as you can and land on the soles of your feet.

**6. Burpees**

*How to do the exercise*

Start with your feet shoulder-width apart and squat down until your thighs are parallel to the floor.
From the bottom of the squat, place your hands on the floor and kick your legs out behind you into a press-up position.
Push up until your arms are straight and then tuck in your legs at the bottom of the squat position.
Drive upwards through your heels until you are six inches off the floor and then repeat.

**7. Handstand Wall Walk**

*How to do the exercise*

Position yourself in a handstand position with your feet planted against a wall.
Move your hands forward and walk down the wall until you reach the bottom.

**8. Wide-grip Pull-ups**

*How to do the exercise*

Grab the bar with your palms facing away from you and your arms fully extended.
Your hands should be as wide as you can comfortably get them.
Squeeze your shoulder blades together, exhale and drive your elbows towards your hips to bring your chin above the bar.
Lower under control back to the start position.

**9. Frozen V-sit**

*How to do the exercise*

Lie down on your back with your arms and legs outstretched and your hands and feet lifted just above the floor.
Begin the exercise by simultaneously raising your torso and legs up to touch your feet.
Hold for five to 10 seconds.

**10. Single Leg Glute Bridge**

*How to do the exercise*

Lie on your back with one leg raised in the air.
Thrust forward and raise your hips off the ground as high as you can.
Slowly lower yourself to the floor.
Clench your glutes at the top of the rep to activate more muscle fibres and see greater growth.

Comment: In the article it says: **"each of which are capable of giving you a full-body workout"**, does it means I can select one of them and it will be full body exercise? Or the complete list is full body exercises where each one is for a separate part of the body?

Comment: Do 10 burpees and you'll know you're working out your entire body.

Comment: I just saw it, and I gotta say, That's intense! The GIFs in this article are very useful.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! They’ve been helpful for me too.